# How do i get all files from directory including sub directories?

Tags: c#, winforms

This is the code:

```
private void SearchForDoc()
        {
            t = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("UserProfile")+"\\documents";
            string[] s = Directory.GetFiles(t, "*.txt",);
```

This will search for txt files in a directory but i want to find also all the text files in its subdirectories.
There should be SearchOption searchOption after the "*.txt",

Answer (score 3):

Use this overload: [Directory.GetFiles Method (String, String, SearchOption)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143316.aspx), where SearchOption is `SearchOption.AllDirectories`.

```
string[] s = Directory.GetFiles(t, "*.txt", SearchOption.AllDirectories);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
string[] s = Directory.GetFiles(t,"*.txt", SearchOption.AllDirectories);
```